# Can I Add Jquery with My Jquery Mobile Scripts in _Layout.Mobile.cshtml?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Initially I do not reference jquery.  I have my _layout.mobile.cshtml able to navigate between pages easily using only jquery mobile 1.4.2.  However, there isn't a loading screen when moving around that I like when I have the standard jquery script referenced. (all in header)

Also, an error pops on the console when I inspect elements in Chrome that states: Cannot set property of 'mobile' as undefined.  Adding the jquery script gets rid of this error as well.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css")"rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

I want to fix these things, but the problem is that when I reference the jquery-1.9.1, any link I go to on the site first displays a body of 2014.  That's it.  That is all on the page.  And when I refresh it the regular page shows up.

I searched the entire project for 2014 and to my surprise nothing actually shows up, which means it has to do with the jquery-1.9.1.min.js file.  Any idea on how to fix this and still include this file?

Answer (score 0):

as far as your first question yes you can, add and  including the bundles too and define them in config file. Regarding to that 2014 problem I believe you might be using some other jquery file also along with  1.9, and why not use the new version. 1.9 have nothing to do with that, usually this kind of things are used in jquery scripts by others like there might be some text like  "xakshdwiyeajksaxx&*$&##sxaasdw" they are usually hidden links

I hope this help

Comment: So I found out I can use the mobile without any jquery mobile.  News to me, but the site is working great!  It turns out there was a tidbit of info in my footer my co-worker added in and made copyright show up, kind of a pain because it didn't display the characters '2014' whatsoever but a simple dumb thing I missed.  Thank you